# CREAR UNA VENTANA DE LOGEO QUE ENVIE A OTRA VENTANA (JFILECHOOSER)

Tags: java, eclipse, rsync

Estoy sincronizando archivos vía ssh con rsync, mi problema es que ya cree una ventana donde solo introduzca nombre de usuario y a su vez me envié a la ventana (JFILECHOOSER) sin embargo no me deja pasar la siguiente ventana. Alguien que me pueda orientar por favor. Anexo código :D

```
public class Login {
private JFrame frame;
//private static Window sendWindow;
    JFrame user = new JFrame("Registro de Usuario");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //sendWindow = new Window();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Login user = new Login();
                    user.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


public Login(){
    initialize();
}
/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel user = new JPanel();
    frame.add(user);
    placeComponents(user);

    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private static void placeComponents(JPanel user) {

    user.setLayout(null);

    JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Usuario");
    userLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
    user.add(userLabel);

    JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
    userText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
    user.add(userText);

    JButton loginButton = new JButton("ENVIAR");
    loginButton.setBounds(20, 85, 85, 30);
    user.add(loginButton);

}
```

}

Este código es la ventana donde solo se introduce el nombre del usuario para que pueda acceder a la siguiente ventana en este caso el JFilechooser y haga la carga de archivos. El siguiente código es del filechooser.

```
public class Window{

private JFrame frame;
private static App sendPath;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    sendPath = new App();
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Window window = new Window();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
    });
}


/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Window() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    //JFrame frame = new JFrame("");

    DemoJFileChooser panel = new DemoJFileChooser();

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel,"Center");
    frame.setSize(panel.getPreferredSize());
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public class DemoJFileChooser extends JPanel
   implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JButton go;
    JLabel message = new JLabel("");

    JFileChooser chooser;
    String choosertitle;

  public DemoJFileChooser() {
    go = new JButton("Do it");
    go.addActionListener(this);
    add(go);
    add(message);
   }

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {            
    chooser = new JFileChooser(); 
    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
    chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    //
    // disable the "All files" option.
    //
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    //    
    if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 
      System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): " 
         +  chooser.getCurrentDirectory());

      System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : " 
         +  chooser.getSelectedFile());
    //PARA WINDOWS PARA ENVIAR //sendPath.setPath(chooser.getSelectedFile().toString()+ "\\" );
      sendPath.setPath(chooser.getSelectedFile().toString()+ "/" );
      try {
        message.setText("Conecting with server...");
            App.daemon();
        message.setText("Generating public key...");
            //App.sshKeyGen();
        message.setText("Sending public key to server...");
            //App.sshBinaries();
        message.setText("SSH conection ...");
            //App.ssh();
        message.setText("RSYNC conection ...");
            //App.rsyncBinaries();
        message.setText("Done");
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
      }
    else {
      System.out.println("No Selection ");
      }
     }

  public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
    return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

}
```

}

Esta es mi clase App,la clase Window solo se "conecta" con la clase App y hace todo el proceso, pero como le agregue una ventan de login ya es donde me perdí

```
public class App extends Window {
  private static String path; 
     public static void daemon() throws Exception{
       System.out.println("Conecting to server ....");
          RSync rsync = new RSync();
             //VARIABLE QUE SE GUARDA DESDE EL OTRO CODIGO DE VETANA DONDE SE INGRESA NOMBRE DE USUARIO
            String variable="";
              rsync.setOptions(new String[{"avz","e","ssh",path,variable+"@192.168.2.219:rsync"});
              ConsoleOutputProcessOutput output = new 
                 ConsoleOutputProcessOutput();
                    output.monitor(rsync.builder());
   }
```

Comment: Hola Mad96. Te pido que por favor coloques tu código como texto (con su correspondiente edición) esto entre otras cosas permite que se copie a un IDE  y se reproduzca el problema. Por otro lado el JFileChooser sirve para mostrar diálogos de carga de archivos cuando dices: ...sin embargo no me deja pasar la siguiente ventana.. lo que intentas expresar es que el JFileChooser no muestra nada? Quedo atento a tus comentarios

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, lo que pasa es que es la primera vez que utilizo la plataforma, al ejecutar el proyecto en eclipse me abre los diálogos de carga de archivo y puedo hacer la sincronizacion de archivos de forma (cliente-servidor). Entonces el objetivo es que primero me abra una venta de login (en el solo se ingresa el nombre del usuario y dar en aceptar) una vez registrado su nombre tiene que abrir a la venta donde muestra para cargar archivos.

Comment: Entonces en una clase java hice un JFrame de login, en otras clase nueva tengo el jfilechooser, el resultado que obtengo es solo me abre la ventana de login pero no abre la siguiente ventana que es el jfilechooser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por atender el comentario.
El efecto visual que buscas es ver que una ventana (tipo dialogo) te pase a otra. Como cuando buscas algo en google y te pasa a la pagina de resultados.

Aunque esto es posible usando dos veces la clase **Windows** es mucho más fácil generar un solo **JFrame** con dos paneles, cuando se cumplen las condiciones necesarias cambias el panel interior por otro. Si usas dos veces la clase **Windows** te enfrentas a estar uniendo dos procesos distintos, es como si google te abriera otra ventana en el explorador cuando consultas algo, es más fácil usar la misma ventana del explorador y solo cambiar el contenido.

Como no tengo la clase **App** ni se exactamente como funciona solo la he simulado con una propia que solo realiza esperas de 1 segundo.

Te explico la estrategía.
Primero se genera un **JFrame** y en el se coloca un panel que se llena con los elementos de la clase **Login** (ya no uso la clase **Login** sino solo el código del panel de la misma).

Al botón se le agrega un evento. Este evento quita del panel de la aplicación todo y luego agrega otro panel que solo tiene en su interior al **Label** message.

Lo que entiendo es que quieres ir viendo los pasos del envió al servidor. Esto se hace con distintos métodos que van realizando distintas acciones en cada etapa (si se hace todo de jalón solo se ve el texto **Done** al final de la ejecución). Cada método genera un hilo de ejecución usando **EventQueue.invokeLater** para poder refrescar la pantalla.

La solución con todo y sus imports es la siguiente. La clase ahora se llama **Aplicacion**:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 *
 * @author alvaro
 */
public class Aplicacion extends JFrame {

   // el chooser se selecciona desde el principio.
   private JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
   // message se inicializa desde el principio
   private JLabel message = new JLabel("");

   public Aplicacion() {
      inicialize();
   }

   /**
    * Agrega el primer panel al JFrame
    */
   private void inicialize() {

      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      JPanel user = new JPanel();
      add(user);
      placeComponents(user);

   }

   /**
    * Pone los elementos del primer panel y agrega el evento al botón
    */
   private void placeComponents(JPanel user) {

      user.setLayout(null);

      JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Usuario");
      userLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
      user.add(userLabel);

      JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
      userText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
      user.add(userText);

      JButton loginButton = new JButton("ENVIAR");
      loginButton.setBounds(20, 85, 85, 30);
      user.add(loginButton);

      // esto agrega una acción al pulsar el botón
      loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        // quita todo del panel principal
        Aplicacion.this.getContentPane().removeAll();
        // genera un segundo panel
        JPanel panelFileChooser = new JPanel();
        // al panel le agrega message
        panelFileChooser.add(message);
        // pone este segundo panel como panel principal
        Aplicacion.this.setContentPane(panelFileChooser);
        // refresca la pantalla
        Aplicacion.this.setVisible(true);
        // invoca la rutina para abrir el file chooser
        invocaChooser();
     }
      });

   }

   /** Abre el filechooser y con el directorio que se elige comienza a trabajar usando la clase App
   */
   public void invocaChooser() {

      chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
      chooser.setDialogTitle("Elija su archivo");
      chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
      //
      // disable the "All files" option.
      //
      chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
      // si eligio un archivo se arranca la ejecución
      if (chooser.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

     System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): "
        + chooser.getCurrentDirectory());

     System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : "
        + chooser.getSelectedFile());
     App sendPath = new App();

     //PARA WINDOWS PARA ENVIAR //sendPath.setPath(chooser.getSelectedFile().toString()+ "\\" );
     sendPath.setPath(chooser.getSelectedFile().toString() + "/");
     try {
        // intenta conectar al servidor 
        message.setText("Conecting with server...");
        Aplicacion.this.setVisible(true);
        invocaDemonio();
     } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
     }

      } else {
     System.out.println("No Selection ");
      }

   }
   /** Invoca al demonio pero lo hace con un hilo.
       Esto permite refrescar la pantalla (la variable message) y 
       y cuando termina invoca a keyGen.
    */
   public void invocaDemonio() {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        try {
           App.daemon();
           message.setText("Generating public key...");
           Aplicacion.this.setVisible(true);
           invocaKeyGen();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
      });
   }

   public void invocaKeyGen() {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        try {
           App.sshKeyGen();
           message.setText("Sending public key to server...");
           Aplicacion.this.setVisible(true);
           invocaBinarios();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
      });
   }

   public void invocaBinarios() {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        try {
           App.sshBinaries();
           message.setText("SSH conection ...");
           Aplicacion.this.setVisible(true);
           invocaSsh();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
      });
   }

   public void invocaSsh() {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        try {
           App.ssh();
           message.setText("RSYNC conection ...");
           Aplicacion.this.setVisible(true);
           invocaSyncBinaries();
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
      });

   }

   public void invocaSyncBinaries() {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        try {
           App.rsyncBinaries();
           message.setText("Done");
           Aplicacion.this.setVisible(true);

        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
      });
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      //sendWindow = new Window();
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        try {
           Aplicacion user = new Aplicacion();
           // esto hace que el sistema operativo ubique la ventana
           user.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
           // esto define el tamaño de la ventana
           user.setSize(450, 300);
           // se pinta la ventana
           user.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
      });
   }
}
```

Con esto al ejecutar obtengo la siguiente salida:

Arranco la aplicación:

[image: pidiendo el nombre]

Luego me pide el directorio:

[image: pidiendo directorio]

Luego comienza con los mensajes enviando el archivo:

[image: Muestra mensaje]

Hasta que llega al Done:

[image: Muestra el último mensaje]

Este es el camino feliz de la ejecución. No estoy manejando los errores que pudieran surgir (lo mínimo que debía hacerse es en cada **catch** actualizar la variable **message** con el error que se presente).

También debo decirte que usar el layout nulo ( donde dice **setLayout(null)** ) es mala practica debería evitarse aunque para salir del paso en una urgencia puede servir de justificación.

Usar **System.out.println** es para ejercicios de escuela o para pruebas demasiado básicas deberías usar un framework de logging como **Log4j**, **LogBack** o **Commons Loggin** si esto es un trabajo profesional.

Los métodos que he generado usando **EventQueue.invokeLater** son una plana. Podrían factorizarse pero es posible que se necesite generar una segunda clase para dejar el código mucho más legible y sencillo.

Espero que lo que te he colocado te sirva. 
De ser así te pido que marques mi respuesta como la correcta a fin de que alguien más que tenga un planteamiento similar al tuyo tenga la confianza en que lo que coloco puede serle de utilidad.

Quedo atento a cualquier comentario.

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, esta es la clase App 
public class App extends Window {
private static String path; 
public static void daemon() throws Exception{
    System.out.println("Conecting to server ....");
    RSync rsync = new RSync();
    //VARIABLE QUE SE GUARDA DESDE EL OTRO CODIGO EN LA VENTANA DE LOGIN
    String variable="";
    rsync.setOptions(new String[]{"-avz","-e","ssh",path,variable+"@192.168.2.219:rsync"});
    ConsoleOutputProcessOutput output = new ConsoleOutputProcessOutput();
    output.monitor(rsync.builder());
}

Comment: Esta es mi clase esta va al servidor donde abre el JFilechooser y puede hacer la carga de archivos, sin embargo me encargaron añadir una ventan de login donde solo ponga el nombre de usuario y se guarde la variable en este caso el Nombre de usuario en la clase App a fin de que pase a la ventana del JFileChooser haga la carga de archivos y listo, en dicha clase App puse un String variable =""; y en la parte donde esta mi IP de mi compu puse el String variable a fin de que reconozca el nombre del usuario que agregue desde la venta Login

Comment: Hola @Mad96. Igual y sería mejor editar la pregunta agregando el código que comentas pues en el comentario no se aprecia bien. Me haces aclaraciones pero no me dices si necesitas más apoyo o si con lo que te he puesto ya puedes completar tu sola el resto. Quedo atento a tus comentarios

Comment: de hecho edite la pregunta y puse la clase App

Comment: Hola @Alvaro C.
Gracias por la aportación y por haberme aclarado mis dudas que tenía, realmente me fue de mucha ayuda, puesto que al modificar mi código y una vez estudiado el código que me puso, pude entender y detectar lo que me faltaba. Ahora lo único que tengo es resolver una duda algo pequeña pues cuando agrego el nombre del usuario esa nombre lo tengo que recuperar como variable. Obviamente tendré que modificar mi pregunta o realizar una nueva. Le estoy agradecida por haberse tomado el tiempo de resolver mi dudas. Una vez más gracias :D

Comment: Que bueno que te sirvio. Nos veremos en una siguiente pregunta entonces. Hasta luego.